# .NET Entity framework for java

Tags: java, entity-framework

i would like to ask, if there is some framework in Java which can automaticly generate entities (objects) from database?
There is a similar possibility in visual studio to "generate model from database".

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Java Persistence API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jpa-137156.html). You can generate [JPA entities from an existing database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.orm.doc/html/files/genJPAEntities.html) in Eclipse.